# Is there a service like Push Code for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, release

The **code push** service in React Native helps to update the application without releasing it on GooglePlay

Is this service also available in Flutter?

[Code Push Reac Native](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push)

A React Native app is composed of JavaScript files and any accompanying images, which are bundled together by the metro bundler and distributed as part of a platform-specific binary (i.e. an .ipa or .apk file). Once the app is released, updating either the JavaScript code (e.g. making bug fixes, adding new features) or image assets, requires you to recompile and redistribute the entire binary, which of course, includes any review time associated with the store(s) you are publishing to.

Answer (score 3):

Deploy app updates instantly
Code push is a cloud service that allows developers to push app updates directly to users' devices.

[ShoreBirrd](https://shorebird.dev/)

Comment: It is a good service.
I have used the demo version